# something wired about lw instruction when I use QtSpim

Tags: mips, qtspim

```
[00400028] 8d090008  lw $9, 8($8);  lw $t1, 0x008($t0) 

[0040002c] 312a0002  andi $10, $9, 2          ; 5: andi $t2,$t1,0x2 

[00400030] 1148fffd  beq $10, $8, -12 [chkswitch-0x00400030]

[00400034] 3c010001  lui $1, 1                ; 7: lw $t3,0x8000($t0) 

[00400038] 00280821  addu $1, $1, $8          

[0040003c] 8c2b8000  lw $11, -32768($1)   

[00400040] 3c010001  lui $1, 1                ; 9: lw $t1, 0x8008($t0)

[00400044] 00280821  addu $1, $1, $8          

[00400048] 8c298008  lw $9, -32760($1)
```

As shown above，the `lw` instruction was translated into 3 machine code when I use `0x8000`， why would this happen？ It seem the result is wrong。

Answer (score 1):

Because the offset for `lw` is a 16-bit signed value, which means that only -32768..+32767 (-0x8000..+0x7FFF) can be represented.

The assembler is "fixing" this for you by converting your invalid instruction into three valid ones:

```
lui $1, 1                # $at = 0x10000
addu $1, $1, $8          # $at += $t0
lw $11, -32768($1)       # $t3 = -32768($at)   (== 32768($t0))
```